# Openstack Permission denied when I generate a picture by python

Tags: python, openstack

I use a program which can generate a picture. I saved it by

```
img.save("/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openstackdashboard/static/dashboard/img/validate.jpeg")
return strs # strs is picture's data
```

Everything goes right when run it alone . But " IOError " occured when I call it by

```
from .auth_code import Create_Validate_Code
auth_code_str = Create_Validate_Code()
```

And horizon says " [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openstack-dashboard/static/dashboard/img/validate.jpeg' ". Could someone help me  ? Thanks a lot .

This is all code to create a picture

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter

_letter_cases = "1234567890" 
_upper_cases = _letter_cases.upper() 
_numbers = ''.join(map(str, range(3, 10))) 
init_chars = ''.join((_letter_cases, _upper_cases, _numbers))
fontType="/usr/share/fonts/lohit-tamil/Lohit-Tamil.ttf"

def create_lines(draw,n_line,width,height):
  line_num = random.randint(n_line[0],n_line[1]) 
  for i in range(line_num):
    begin = (random.randint(0, width), random.randint(0, height))
    end = (random.randint(0, width), random.randint(0, height))
    draw.line([begin, end], fill=(0, 0, 0))

def create_points(draw,point_chance,width,height):
  chance = min(100, max(0, int(point_chance))) 

  for w in xrange(width):
    for h in xrange(height):
      tmp = random.randint(0, 100)
      if tmp > 100 - chance:
        draw.point((w, h), fill=(0, 0, 0))

def create_strs(draw,chars,length,font_type, font_size,width,height,fg_color):
  c_chars = random.sample(chars, length)
  strs = ' %s ' % ' '.join(c_chars) 

  font = ImageFont.truetype(font_type, font_size)
  font_width, font_height = font.getsize(strs)

  draw.text(((width - font_width) / 3, (height - font_height) / 3),strs, font=font, fill=fg_color)

  return ''.join(c_chars)



def Create_Validate_Code(size=(120, 30),
                             chars=init_chars,
                             img_type="GIF",
                             mode="RGB",
                             bg_color=(255, 255, 255),
                             fg_color=(0, 0, 255),
                             font_size=18,
                             font_type=fontType,
                             length=4,
                             draw_lines=True,
                             n_line=(1, 2),
                             draw_points=True,
                             point_chance = 2):

  width, height = size 
  img = Image.new(mode, size, bg_color) 
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img) 
  if draw_lines:
    create_lines(draw,n_line,width,height)
  if draw_points:
    create_points(draw,point_chance,width,height)
  strs = create_strs(draw,chars,length,font_type, font_size,width,height,fg_color)

  params = [1 - float(random.randint(1, 2)) / 100,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1 - float(random.randint(1, 10)) / 100,
            float(random.randint(1, 2)) / 500,
            0.001,
            float(random.randint(1, 2)) / 500
            ]
  img = img.transform(size, Image.PERSPECTIVE, params) 

  img = img.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE) 

  img.save("/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openstack-dashboard/static/dashboard/img/validate.jpeg")

  return strs
```

Comment: Why are you trying to save files into the middle of your site-packages in the first place? That's almost guaranteed to be a bad idea, even if by some strange chance you have permission to do it.

Comment: Also, I don't believe the first version really works. Most likely you aren't actually calling that `img.save` code anywhere, which is why you don't get an exception. The error is clearly telling you that you don't have permission to write that file, and why would importing some other module or calling some other function cause that, especially when you shouldn't have had permission in the first place?

Comment: I want to use the generated picture displayed on the horizon..

Comment: That comment answers absolutely nothing. What makes you think the picture has to be crammed into your site-packages for you to display it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code to create and save the file is inside the function `Create_Validate_Code`. In your initial version, you never call that function anywhere. Therefore, it never tries to create and save the file, so it never fails.

When you add this:

```
from .auth_code import Create_Validate_Code
auth_code_str = Create_Validate_Code()
```

… now you're calling the function. So now it fails. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the third-party module you're using; you could do the same thing with just this:

```
Create_Validate_Code()
```

---

Meanwhile, the *reason* that creating the file fails is that you don't have write access to directories in the middle of your system's `site-packages`. This is by design. This is why operating systems have permissions in the first place—to stop some buggy or malicious code run as a normal user from screwing up programs and data needed by the entire system.

Create the file somewhere you *do* have access to, like some place in your home directory, or the temporary directory, or whatever's appropriate to whatever you're trying to do, and the problem will go away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer firstly. I still have some problem with your  answer. It also fails even I code " image.save('/home/picture.jpeg') ". And what should I do to fix it ? Using " Create_Validate_Code() "  instead of " from .auth_code import Create_Validate_Code
auth_code_str = Create_Validate_Code() " ???

Comment: Well, I sincerely doubt your home directory is `/home`. It may be something like `/home/changzhi`, or `/Users/changzhi`, or `/mnt/remote/013/013479`, or… Normally you want to either (a) use [`os.path.expanduser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) and a path like `'~/picture.jpeg'`, or (b) just use a relative path and let the user pick the right place to put things instead of trying to hardcode it into the script.

Comment: Thank for your answer again . It fails when I use img.save('/root/picture.jpeg'). The code can run normally alone when I use any path . Once I use " from .auth_code import Create_Validate_Code
auth_code_str = Create_Validate_Code() " it fails when I use any path...

Comment: Once again, "the code can run normally alone" only because the code isn't actually running in your "alone" case. If you never call a function, it can't fail. That doesn't mean the function is correct, it just means you never call it. I don't know how many other ways to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the final app as Administrator/root? That usually fixes any "Permission denied" errors while programming.

Comment: You really think he's on Windows with paths like `/usr/lib/…/`? Also, "just run as Administrator/root, then you have no permissions problems" is a really bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't save data deep within your Python installation. It's really bad practice, which is why the OS is preventing you from doing it. Save the picture somewhere in your home folder.

Comment: @changzhi: See my answer. It only seems like it "goes okay when I can run the code alone" because you don't actually run the code.